# How to select documents by field range of values in MongoDB C# driver?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a collection named Items. Documents in the Items collection have a field named "LocationId." How do I select, and bring back to server, all Item documents that have a LocationId that matches a list, array, etc (whatever collection you prefer) of Location Ids?

[image]

tl:dr for clarity:
 1. Have Items collection.
 2. Have list of LocationIds, e.g. "1, 5, 6, 12, 99" on the server.
 3. Need to bring back all Item documents that have a LocationId listed in the collection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can build simple queries using lambda expression, MongoDB.Driver supports it

```
var collection = database.GetCollection<Item>("Item");
var list = await collection.Find(x => locationIds.Contains(x.LocationId)).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Thanks mofenko, I will come back to accept the answer once I try it late tonight.

Comment: This should work, but this isn't LINQ. It's just a query with a lambda expression.

Comment: @VSO Can you check your mongoDb.Driver version? 2.0.1 should have next method signature http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/current/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_IMongoCollectionExtensions_Find__1_1.htm

Comment: Version: 2.0.0.828 - we are using NuGet. I guess that's my problem. Is there any other way to do it or pretty much select items in each location and then combine lists?

Answer (score 1):

I was given this solution, which works with the older driver:

```
 var locations = new BsonValue[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
 var collection = database.GetCollection<Item>("Item");
 var data = collection
            .Find(Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.In("LocationId", locations))
            .Project(x => Mapper.Map<BsonDocument, ItemViewModel>(x))
            .ToListAsync().Result;
```

The funny thing is that I don't know what "new BsonValue[]{}" does. Guess is bson array.

Answer (score 1):

here's an alternate way using builders/filters.

```
var ids = new List<Int32> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
var filter = Builders<Item>.Filter.AnyIn("LocationId", ids);
var collection = database.GetCollection<Item>("Item");
var results = await collection.FindAsync(filter);

var locations = await results.ToListAsync();
```